# Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseAnnotationProcessorClasspath'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk, classpath

I have already extracted **APK** from my app, but now when I try to extract from the app, it gives this error.
This is despite the fact that no library has been added to the app.

**Error Message:**

> Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileRelease'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseAnnotationProcessorClasspath'.
> Could not find support-annotations.jar (com.android.support:support-annotations:25.3.0).
> Searched in the following locations:
> https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/support/support-annotations/25.3.0/support-annotations-25.3.0.jar

> Possible solution:
>
> - Declare repository providing the artifact, see the documentation at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/declaring_repositories.html

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        //noinspection JcenterRepositoryObsolete
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.4'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        //noinspection JcenterRepositoryObsolete
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        maven {
            url "https://repository.aspose.com/repo/" }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "https://maven.neshan.org/artifactory/public-maven" }
        subprojects {
            project.configurations.all {
                resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                    if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms'
                            && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                        details.useVersion "12.0.1"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**gradle-wrapper.properties**

```
#Mon Jul 20 12:03:01 IRDT 2020
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.6.4-all.zip
```

**No changes have been made in the code, we just want to get another output.**

In general, what is the reason that **Google** does these things, the program that is written and output from it gives an error like this after some time and we have to make a change in the program so that it can output apk.

Comment: You have to update the gradle

Comment: What version?  You know the reason for this ridiculous work of Google, why we have to change the version of the program that was written and outputted after some time to output it. @Muraino

Comment: try to create new android project and update the gradle with what you have on the new one... provided that compile

Comment: if you are unable to fix it, let me know then I will post an answer for you

Comment: If I want to create another project, the user must delete the previous version from his phone, I don't want this to happen to the program, because this is not correct, do you have another solution? @Muraino

Comment: I don't mean you should create a new project and discard current one, rather I meant you can copy the updated gradle version from the new project you created  and paste in yours... I will update your gradle now.. wait

Comment: what is the version of your gradle wrapper.. can you confirm

Comment: updated post and add gradle.wrapper @Muraino

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247682/discussion-between-mohammad-hasan-salmanian-and-muraino).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `gradle-wrapper.properties` to

```
 #Wed Nov 20 09:57:01 EST 2020
 distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
 distributionPath=wrapper/dists
 zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
 zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
 distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```

Update your gradle version and replace jcenter with mavenCenter()

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
   }
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    google()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com'
    }
    maven {
        url "https://repository.aspose.com/repo/" }
    maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    maven { url "https://maven.neshan.org/artifactory/public-maven" }
    subprojects {
        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                    details.useVersion "12.0.1"
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
 }
```

- Build/ clean Project
- Sync your gradle
- Invalidate cache and restart